# How to join elements in a list with a separator in Python?

Tags: python

```
  lst=['list 1','list 2','list 3']
  lst1='_'.join(lst)
  print(lst1)
```

Output is coming as `list 1_list 2_list 3`
Expected output is `list_1 list_2 list_3`

How to join elements in Python with separator?

Comment: It seems like you _don't_ want to join them with the separator, you want to replace that character in the individual strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> lst=['list 1','list 2','list 3']
>>> out = [l.replace(' ', '_') for l in lst]
>>> print(*out)
list_1 list_2 list_3
```